# Calculate the current date from given seconds

Tags: date

You have been provided the current time as the number of seconds that have elapsed since the start of this century (i.e since the beginning of 2000) as input. You have to compute the date that the input time corresponds to.Note that the output required is an integer in yyyymmdd format where yyyy corresponds to year, mm to month and dd to date.

**Note:without using array concept**

*Example:*
currDate(122352353)=20031117 ( it corresponds to 17th November 2003).

Comment: Come on, this is a homework from your college course. Don't be stupid and try to have others do your homework: you will never learn anything this way.

Comment: I don't think it is SA format. It is not hard algorithm, but not interesting. If you can't do it yourself, show your existing attempts and what concrete you can't.

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."* -- StackOverflow "Offtopic reasons"

Answer (score 0):

```
long timeInMilliSecs = 122352353000L;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    try {
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Jan 01 2000"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// all done
    long d = cal.getTimeInMillis() + timeInMilliSecs;
    cal.setTimeInMillis(d);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Always work with timeinmillis. This will help you easily convert any date. So first thing is convert your 2000 date to millis and add the given date(122352353 in this case) to it after converting to millis. That is it! Now just convert the milli time to date.

Comment: I believe this is Java. How did you figure out OP wanted an answer in Java, and not in any of the other programming languages out there?

Comment: @Sumurai8: probably because this is homework, and in school they learn C or java.